# Please check my solution (Uniform convergence of the functions)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Here is the question in my real analysis textbook.

$f$ is a continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Say $f_n(x) = {n \over 2}\int_{x-{1 \over n }}^{x+{1 \over n }} f(t) dt$

Show the $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

---

In fact, the textbook itself solve this by M.V.T for integral.

But I tried a different way like the below.

$(sol)$ For $\forall x \in [0,1]$, consider the  $I_n = [x- {1 \over n }, x+{1 \over n }]$

Since $f$ is a continuous on $I_n$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I_n $

Therefore, by the definition of the uniform continuity

$(1)$ $\exists {2 \over n} \leq \delta $ s.t. $\Vert x-y \Vert < \delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert <{2\epsilon \over n } $

$(2)$plus, By Archimedes  $\exists k \in \mathbb N s.t. n \geq k \Rightarrow {2\epsilon \over n } < \epsilon$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$
$\Vert f_n(x) - f(x) \Vert = \Vert {n \over 2}\int_{x-{1 \over n }}^{x+{1 \over n }} (f(t) - f(x)) dt  \Vert \leq  {n \over 2}\int_{x-{1 \over n }}^{x+{1 \over n }} \Vert f(t) - f(x) \Vert dt \leq {n \over 2 } {2 \over n } \epsilon =\epsilon $

Hence, $\exists k s.t. n \geq k  \Rightarrow \Vert f_n(x) - f(x) \Vert <
\epsilon$ (Uniform convergence).

I don't have a confidence my solution is right or not. Please check my idea and solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution is correct and I would have answered it this way. I don't know why they use MVT for integrals for this.

Comment: I would express  appreciation for checking my solution, Mr. @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: There are some issues. You start with $\forall x\in [0,1]$, but you do not quantify $n$. Do you mean "for every positive integer $n$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I_n$"? Then the $\epsilon$ is unquantified, presumably you want something like "Let $\epsilon>0$ be given/arbitrary". Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|< 2\epsilon/n$. By $\|\cdot\|$, I assume you mean the sup/max norm on functions, so when you write $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$, I suppose you mean sup/max as a function of $y$ (since $x$ is fixed). But anyhow, it is not clear...

Comment: (cont.) why the value of $\delta$ will be larger than $2/n$. Or perhaps by $\exists 2/n<\delta$, you mean there exists a $\delta$, then there exists an $n$ such that $2/n<\delta$. But there is an issue with this, because you say "$f$ is uniformly continuous on $I_n$", meaning that the $\delta>0$ that exists might depend on $n$.